# adding a color theme in spyder in preferences

Tags: python, ide, color-scheme

I am using Spyder to do my Python coding. At the moment I am trying to add another color theme to my editor. Is there a way I can do it if I have a source code for that theme (i.e. pygment file)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the theme, edit the spyder.ini, found in ~/.spyder2/.spyder.ini or c:\Users\[yourusername]\.spyder2\.spyder.ini [color_schemes] section [as described here](https://github.com/pshchelo/spyder-color-solarized/blob/master/README.rst):

Comment: As of Spyder 4.0, this file has now moved to ~/.spyder-py3/config/spyder.ini. If you upgraded your install from 3.0, you may have a non-functional file where MapLion describes, and will get very frustrated when you change it and nothing happens.